# MSMQ with Directory Services integration for PKI implementation

Tags: active-directory, directory, msmq, directoryservices, pki

currently, we have a situation. We have MSMQ services hosted which uses self-signed SSL certificates for data encryption and mutual authentication of the publisher / MQ. It actually uses Encryt and sign option for encrypting and signing data with a self-signed certificate and validating data.

We are using self-signed certificates as we are not AD / CA enabled.

Now, we want to move to Active directory / CA enabled services, hence, in order to implement mutual authentication / Encrypt and sign with CA certificates, there will be a need to have public certificates of each of the systems on either side.

Not sure if having a public repository of CA certificates accessible is a good idea here??

To circumvent this, we are thinking of using MSMQ with active directory services integration which would do this internally without each system having to know each other's public certificates.

Is anyone aware of whether this is done else where or if this is possible? need some help here?? if someone can point to some documentations ??